# JSF - built-in methods that create url query string from f:param and includeViewParams

Tags: jsf, viewparams

Most of my page navigation uses get requests and now I have a form where the parameters should be included as query-string parameters using `f:param` inside `h:commandButton` or checking attributes for `includeViewParams` to use `UIViewParameter`.

I do not want to use `includeViewParams` since this would include all view defined parameters, I just want to use the ones provided as child's of the command component.

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText value="#{bean.value1}"/>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value2}"/>
    <p:commandButton action="#{utilBean.performActionParams(outcome)}">
        <f:param name="key1" value="#{bean.value1}"/>
        <o:param name="key1" value="#{bean.value2}" converter="#{bean.converter}/>
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>

public String performActionParams(final String outcome)
{
    final UriBuilder uriBuilder = UriBuilder.fromPath(outcome);

    final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(context);

    for (final UIComponent child : component.getChildren())
        if (child instanceof UIParameter)
        {
            final UIParameter param = (UIParameter) child;

            if (!param.isDisable() && !StringUtils.isBlank(param.getName()))
            {
                final Object value = param.getValue();

                if (value != null)
                    uriBuilder.queryParam(param.getName(), value);
            }
        }

    return uriBuilder.build().toString();
}
```

This logic is not really complicated but it seems so redundant since it seems to be the same logic as in `h:link` and `h:button`.

So does someone knows where this logic is implemented?

Comment: Don't really understand your question. The check is done in the `RESTORE_VIEW` phase, with a call to `ViewDeclarationLanguage.getViewMetadata()` which, in your case will return an instance of `ViewMetadata` **because** you're using GET navigation *and* your destination page has a `<f:metaData/>`. What is your question? Do you want to override metadata handling?

Comment: Somewhere in jsf there must be the code which reads `f:param` from within `h:link` and creates a target uri. I editet answer and posted my code which basically is a workaround and does the same as `h:link`, just for the usage with a commandbutton. I just think my code is redundant since somewhere in jsf this is already coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mojarra, this kind of logic is also buried in [`OutcomeTargetRenderer#getEncodedTargetURL()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.1.19/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/OutcomeTargetRenderer.java#162) (and in [`HtmlBasicRenderer#getParamList()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.1.19/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/HtmlBasicRenderer.java#HtmlBasicRenderer.getParamList%28com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.UIComponent%29)). The only public part which is provided by the API is the [`ViewHandler#getBookmarkableURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#getBookmarkableURL%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map,%20boolean%29), however it takes a `Map` as parameter map, not a list of `UIParameter` components.

I'm not sure what the concrete functional requirement is, but so far it seems that you actually want to fire a simple GET request and not a POST request. In that case, you should be using `<h:link>` or `<h:button>` (or `<p:button>`). Their renderers extend from `OutcomeTargetRenderer` having this logic internally implemented. You can just use EL in `outcome` attribute (the probable assumption that this is not possible was perhaps your reason why you tried a command button).

```
<p:button outcome="#{outcome}">
    <f:param name="key1" value="#{value1}" />
    <o:param name="key1" value="#{value2}" converter="#{bean.converter}" />
</p:button>
```

---

**Update**: as per the comments, the concrete functional requirement is basically to turn a JSF POST form along with the submitted data into a GET request. In that case, it'd be easier if you bind the inputs to a `Map` which is ready for use in `getBookmarkableURL()`.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.params.key1}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.params.key2}" />
<p:commandButton value="#{bean.submit(outcome)}" />
```

with

```
private Map<String, String> params;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    params = new HashMap<>();
}

public String submit(outcome) {
    // ...

    return context.getApplication().getViewHandler()
        .getBookmarkableURL(context, outcome, params, false);

    // TODO: Is faces-redirect=true also considered?
}
```

Comment: But the form input parameters '#{bean.query}' for example would not be evaluated since we have no postback in this case (those values could also be set via viewParam). I edited my example to use a form with input parameters, sorry to forgot that. Will have a look at your method references.

Comment: Oh, this way. That makes completely sense. Well, there's a way, I will update the answer.

Comment: Doesn't need your map be of type: `Map<String, List<String>>`?. For certain use cases this looks promising, but what if not just String's with `inputText` should be handled (hence the Converter in my example using `o:param`). Furthermore if the bean values could also be set via `f:viewParam` this would force me to always use a map (just with String's?) for those or at least create it. Maybe using combination of  `HtmlBasicRenderer.getParamList()` with `getBookmarkableURL()`. But this would enforce to be tied to mojarra which is also not a good idea.